# How to bind certain Values from a datatable to Combo box in MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox

I did bind a Combo-box with a datatable but now i need a modification so that the Combobox shows a certain values from the table it is bound to.

Thanks in advance ,,

Answer (score 0):

Here - you can bind to a table as is, or a query. If you click the elipses, a query wizard will open up for you.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a simpler method than making it a query ??

Comment: Not really @GeboA